# PyCharm crashes on README.md files (on Linux in Docker)

Tags: python, pycharm

Running PyCharm 2023.1.1 (Community Edition) on Linux in Docker, I get the following error when trying to edit `.md` files like `README.md`:

```
 [0628/172358.898878:FATAL:setuid_sandbox_host.cc(157)] The SUID sandbox helper binary was found, but is not configured correctly. Rather than run without sandboxing I'm aborting now. You need to make sure that /pycharm-community-2023.1.1/jbr/lib/chrome-sandbox is owned by root and has mode 4755.

Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 0):

As root in the docker container:

```
# chown root:root /pycharm-community-2023.1.1/jbr/lib/chrome-sandbox
# chmod 755       /pycharm-community-2023.1.1/jbr/lib/chrome-sandbox
# chmod u+s       /pycharm-community-2023.1.1/jbr/lib/chrome-sandbox
```